# Can I move a figure after creating it?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I'm trying to create shapes with c# to my xaml application, the best way to do it would be create a shape at 0,0, draw the lines and then move the shape to its location.

Is it possible? Is it me or does not Path, PathGeometry or PathFigure have move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the shape to another location either by setting the location to another point by code or in xaml itself. But if u want an animation, then refer to some tutorials. I would recommend you to trial all animations using Blend.

Some link on how to do animation:
http://dotnetapp.com/blog/2012/08/26/how-to-create-simple-animation-in-your-windows-phone-app/

Answer (score 0):

In order to move UI elements you need to either set a new margin thickness or you need to put it on a canvas and set its canvas position. If you wanted it animated do the above but put it in a timer tick event.